# Is there a way to add object attributes on destructure?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say for example you you have an object `foobar`:

```js
const foobar = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  baz: 3,
  qux: 4,
}
```

And you wanted to on destructure add together specific elements. Say `foo` and `baz` into a constant `foobaz`. Is there a way to do that inline during destructure or is combination later required?

**Edit for clarification:**

I am looking for if functionality like this is possible. Without defining the value then adding them during deconstruction.

```js
const { foobaz = foo + baz, barqux = bar + qux } = foobar

console.log(foobaz); // 4
console.log(barqux); // 6
```

Comment: Short and sweet: no, it's not possible.

Comment: I mean, at that point you're just declaring a getter for your object that will return the sum of the two properties. [Getters in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Comment: No, you'll need to write `const { foo, bar, baz, qux } = foobar, foobaz = foo + baz, barqux = bar + qux;`.

Comment: I *hate* this, but it's technically possible so I'll leave it as a comment:  `with (foobar) var foobaz = foo + baz, barqux = bar + qux;`  Please don't use this technique.  `with` is deprecated anyway.